# Vue delimiters not working in root when using components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, delimiter

For the code below, delimiters aren't working

```
<div id="some-div">${something}</div>

const component1 = Vue.component("comp-1", {});
const component2 = Vue.component("comp-2", {});

new Vue({
    el: "#some-div",
    data: {
        something: "Anything",
    },
    delimiters: ['${', '} '],
});
```

When I run this code, HTML output is as follows

${something}

It is not parsing my custom delimiters, I have no clue why this is happening, help is much appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: there should be a comma at the end of the data: {} and before delimiters

Comment: I have added the comma in the question, that is not the problem though @samayo

Answer (score 0):

I made a silly mistake, I have extra space after the closing bracket which is why it didn't work.